Info on the word "compossess"?
I'm reading the Cambridge Medieval History collection (vol V, ch 5) and I've come across the word composses/s a few times now, but cannot find any information on or definition for this word. I'll give a couple of examples from the book.


".., linked together by compossession and the duty of blood-revenge." -
"...in any case it would compossess a lofty tower for attack and defence..."


Just from context and the word itself I'm guessing it means something like "possess together", but I'm really curious as to why I can't find any mention of this word online anywhere.

Composition - "money given to a person who had been wronged or injured by the person responsible for the act" - would be a more appropriate word in the first example, and goes along with the mention of blood-debt.  However, this meaning doesn't apply to the second example.

The first one might be 'a common compassion'; the second looks like 'comprise'. But conjecture; I can't find anything convincing.

The OED offers:

† compossessor noun
Obsolete. rare. A joint possessor. 1611 1611   Compossesseur, a compossessor; a ioynt possessor; one that..hath part
in a thing with another. —R. Cotgrave, Dictionarie of French &
English Tongues Source: Oxford English
Dictionary (login required)


Thank you for this excellent resource for historical words. The new oxford ed on my ipad didnt come up with anything when searching for this word, and google mustve considered it a typo, it only gave me definitions for possess and compose. The author of this chapter also used "compossessor" a couple times. Its an older book to be sure, but not so old as to expect regular usage of such an outdated word. Fun stuff!

Note the title of that source: Dictionarie of French & English Tongues. I got a couple of hits in English publications when I searched Google Books for compossessor, but there were dozen if not hundreds of matches in French (and German) text. And my Google Books is configured for "English only", so I guess those are just the relatively small number of publications that GB has misclassified for language. In short, I don't think there ever was a time when compossessor was really "an English word".

@FumbleFingers — At the very least, it was “really an English word” in 1611.
